# How to do a "chroot jail" for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I need to run unsafe code and get a return value. Can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
function buildCards(e) {
  const accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);    
  const messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  const mail = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  const thread = mail.getThread();
  var send_data = ...
  var response = authenticateAndFetch(send_data);

  const retval = function(){return eval(response)}()
  return retval
}
```

This will get `response` from the server and run it locally. I would like to minimize the environment that `response` has access to. Is this approach sufficient for isolating the execution of response?

Comment: Where will the JavaScript be executed? If it's in a browser, the environment it can access will already be pretty restricted. And will be browser-dependent.

Comment: Is this going to be used in an app which accesses mail from multiple users or part of a deployment script?

Comment: This code is run on Google's end, I'm adding the <kbd>google-apps-script</kbd> tag. This script is running on the users' behalf by Google. But the "response" data is coming from a third-party untrusted server.

Comment: For an add-on you have to whitelist the URLs you access, so unless you're using your own server as a proxy and letting the add-on user specify their own endpoint to query through you, you'll have to know the endpoint already. If you are proxying through your servers, why not have your servers do the response eval in your own sandboxed manner?

Comment: I second the idea, to ensure the data you are recieved is from a trust URL, Cert, DNSSEC and then execution risk is minimzed.Otherwise you are going to have to run something like a full *NIX OS in the browser to encapsulate just that command.

Comment: I return the entire card-building javascript from PHP on my server. But still it is best practice to isolate if possible. So that is what my question is here.

Comment: Sadly there are no features in Javascript that allow you create a jail/container inside of JavaScript. Every script is essentially in control of the JS process the browser creates (Modern browsers jail every tab). It would be up to the browser and the users's setting to determine what functions will be considered malicious(canvas). Your best bet would be to encapsulate the received code, but that will really only prevent the script from accessing other variables and functions of your script. Check this out: https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/javascript/best-practices.md